# Qt4.8 + CMake 2.8.5 on OSX 10.5.8 can't link

Tags: macos, qt, linker, cmake, osx-leopard

I'm using Qt4.8 on `OSX Leopard` and instead of `qmake`+`QtCreator` I want to compile a very simple [project](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/images/2/25/QtTest-Package-Example.zip) using `CMake` on OSX to understand how to do a package.

While the very same project compiles and links smoothly under Linux, under my OSX box, this is the error message I always get in the linking phase:

```
ld warning: in /Library/Frameworks//QtGui.framework/QtGui, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Library/Frameworks//QtCore.framework/QtCore, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols:
  "QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for TestFormin moc_TestForm.cxx.o
  "QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for TestFormin moc_TestForm.cxx.o
  "QWidget::actionEvent(QActionEvent*)", referenced from:
      vtable for TestFormin moc_TestForm.cxx.o
  "QCoreApplication::translate(char const*, char const*, char const*, QCoreApplication::Encoding)", referenced from:
```

etcetera etcetera.

This happens for every project I want to compile with cmake.
Any idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what architecture (`i386`,`x86_64`) is being used by `cmake` (`CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`). Try suggesting the architecture to `cmake`:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!
I must only keep the x86_64 architecture because my Qt libraries are provided only in that architecture.